# Random value in nVidia CG language shader (Unity)

Tags: random, unity-game-engine, shader, cg

I'm diving into CG shaders. I'm baking a vertex shader that needs one random constant (computed just once at start time). I know that in Unity it's pretty easy to pass a value from a script to the shader, but I'd like to know if there is any way to have *the shader* create this random constant for me.
Searching for this didn't help me that much so far. So thanks for any help!

Steak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really. You can use some other parameter (like time, or x location for the model) and run frac() or something to get a cgheesy random value, but no direct way in the shader (that's remotely efficient).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realized this myself recently and I see the efficiency reasons. With your help I'm totally sure of what I'm doing now. Thanks